# Spring boot Activiti trying to read all the data in act_ge_bytearray table causing performance issue

Tags: java, apache, spring-boot, workflow, activiti

I Have spring-boot `activiti` project with `activiti-spring-boot-starter` of `Spring boot` version `2.1.6` and `activiti` version `7.0.1.M1`.

When I try to deploy the application in `JBoss EAP 7.0`, it is taking a lot of time to come up when `act_ge_bytearray` table nearing `200 MB`, it is giving `OutOfMerrory` error when it crosses `200MB` size when I truncate that table it's coming up very fast and not getting out of memory until the size of the table goes to `100 MB`.

There seems to be some issue with `activiti + Spring boot`. 
When I use older versions of `activiti(5.18)` and `spring(4.x)` didn't face any issues

Thanks in advance.